# How to delete selected duplicated line from file using perl script

Tags: regex, file, perl, file-handling

Let's say I am having file a.txt which is having following content.

```
aa
aa
bb
cc
dd
ee
ff
ee
gg
```

I want following output -

```
aa
aa
bb
cc
dd
ee
ff
gg
```

Note that I want delete particular duplication of lines only: `ee`.
How can I do that following one liner I tried.

```
perl -ne 'print unless $a{$_}++' a.txt
```

but it is deleting all duplicated lines.

Comment: So do you want to keep repeated lines when they are next to each other?

Comment: no , i just want to delete targeted duplicated lines , like if i target ee then script should delete ee duplication and keep other duplicated lines as it is , and if i target aa then it can only delete aa line duplication and not delete ee

Comment: oh, ok. just add that condition then, `perl -wlne'$tgt = "ee"; print unless $h{$_}++ and $_ eq $tgt' file`.  Can also make the target be read as an argument (instead of hard-coded), if there's benefit to that.

Comment: (and drop the `-w` switch since it'll warn for `main::h`...)

Comment: how to give multiple target in $tgt variable if i want to delete multiple targeted duplication ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232439/discussion-between-deepak-kulkarni-and-zdim).

Comment: Can specify targets in an array, `... @tgt = qw(one two);` and then check whether the line matches any one element, for instance using `any` from `List::Util`.  Then you'd need to name the line that is read since you'll need `$_` for `any` ... so it becomes a little cumbersome for a "one"-liner

Comment: Since this adds up I posted an answer ... let me know if there's more variations or things to add or account for.  Then you may want to edit the question to make it clearer and state the additional requirements in it (for yet other people who may look at this page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove duplicates of only specific ("target") lines add that condition

```
perl -lne'$tgt = "ee"; print unless $h{$_}++ and $_ eq $tgt' file
```

If there may be multiple such targets, then check whether the current line matches any one of them. A nice tool for that is `any` from [List::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util)

```
perl -MList::Util=any -lne'
    $line=$_; 
    @tgt = qw(ee aa); 
    print unless $h{$line}++ and any { $_ eq $line} @tgt
' file
```

Target(s) can be read from the command line as arguments, if there is a benefit to not have them hardcoded.

Note: In older versions `any` is in [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils), and not in `List::Util`.

Comment: Hi zdim, 2 nd one liner solition is not working getting following error - "any" is not exported by the List::Util module
Can't continue after import errors at -e line 0
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

Comment: @deepakkulkarni That's probably an older version of Perl, so with old module versions.  Originally `any` was in [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) (and not in `List::Util`) so try that